# Is there a way to apply a function for a particle when it's first emitted from the ParticleSystem in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system, particles

When a particle is emitted I wanted to calculate the rotation of the particle. Right now, I'm updating the entire particle system to rotate towards a certain direction, which means particles already emitted will switch directions until they die if the particle system rotates.

This is my rotate function (in the script attached to the particle system) that updates the particle system.

```
void lookAtTarget()
    {
        Vector3 lookPos = fingerAim.transform.position - transform.position;
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * 10.5f);
    }
```

Update function:

```
void Update {
   transform.position = player.transform.position;
   lookAtTarget();
}
```

Basically, I want to apply `lookAtTarget` once when the particle is first emitted. Is there anyway how to do this in Unity

Comment: untested but I believe you can use [GetParticles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.GetParticles.html) on the particle system to obtain an array of particles. from there you can apply the lookAt to each of the particles.

Comment: But once you get the particles how do you the apply function once when it's first emitted?

Answer (score 1):

```
ParticleSystem m_System;
ParticleSystem.Particle[] m_Particles;
int prevNumParticles = 0;

private void LateUpdate()
{
    InitializeIfNeeded();

    int numParticlesAlive = m_System.GetParticles(m_Particles);

    if (numParticlesAlive != prevNumParticles)
        ParticleControl(m_Particles[0]); //reference the newest particle (might be last in array)

    prevNumParticles = numParticlesAlive;
}

private void ParticleControl(particle)
{
     // do look at for the particle here
}

void InitializeIfNeeded()
{
    if (m_System == null)
        m_System = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();

    if (m_Particles == null || m_Particles.Length < m_System.main.maxParticles)
        m_Particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[m_System.main.maxParticles];
}
```